# Safest way of handling untrusted javascript objects? JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is JSON notation the safest way to handle untrusted javascript objects?
I'm moving some objects between sandboxes in node.js and I really don't want any of the code in those objects to run outside of the sandboxes, ever.

Comment: What's an "untrusted javascript object"? If you want to run unsafe code you can use the `vm` module.

Comment: What do the objects hold? Not all data can be serialized into JSON.

Comment: untrusted javascript object = user submitted code. What cannot be serialized to JSON? I'm thinking functions (methods) could be tricky, and I really need those.

Comment: Can I just store the objects in an array and pass them around the way they are? Is there any risk with constructors/destructors being executed?

Comment: uh, you can't put functions in JSON.  you can certainly put strings of code in JSON, but then you could put strings in whatever format you like and they'd still be harmless.